# Perl Script to extract the Lowest Dope Score from MODELLER output log file

Tags: perl

From the following file, I need to print the line which consists of lowest `Dope score`. I am facing the problem in how to parse the columns and find the lowest `Dope score`.

Any help is appreciated.

```
 Summary of successfully produced models:
    Filename                          molpdf     DOPE score    GA341 score
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    1A4SA.B99990001.pdb           3116.26953   -54055.24609        1.00000
    1A4SA.B99990002.pdb           3081.24854   -54028.02734        1.00000
    1A4SA.B99990003.pdb           3188.48535   -53395.08594        1.00000
    1A4SA.B99990004.pdb           3093.55493   -54574.60156        1.00000
    1A4SA.B99990005.pdb           3141.67847   -53716.92188        1.00000
    1A4SA.B99990006.pdb           3084.89136   -54276.48828        1.00000
    1A4SA.B99990007.pdb           3081.57983   -53949.57031        1.00000
    1A4SA.B99990008.pdb           3060.45142   -54121.53125        1.00000
    1A4SA.B99990009.pdb           3080.59766   -54202.00000        1.00000
    1A4SA.B99990010.pdb           3065.07520   -54293.01172        1.00000
```

Comment: Please show the code that you need help with

Answer (score 0):

- Assuming you have all the lines in an array `@lines`...

The following illustrates the process:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use Scalar::Util qw<looks_like_number>;

# putting a scalar as a list receiver, 
# guarantees that, you'll only get one--and only one--value.
my ( $low_line ) 
    = 
      # unpack the bundled cargo
      map  { $_->[1] }
      # sort the lines by DOPE score...
      sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] }
      # having attained that score by filtering 
      # out by those that look like a number...
      grep { looks_like_number( $_->[0] ) } 
      # having paired the 3rd column (delimited by spaces)
      # and the line...
      map  { [ (split)[2], $_ ] }
      # from all the lines in the file.
      @lines
    ;
```

I'm not going to cover opening input and that, but I will show you an equivalent 
while loop:

```
my ( $min_score, $min_line );

while ( <$input_file> ) {
    # here we're invoking the most *standard* behavior of the split function...
    next unless my $score = (split)[2];
    # forget non-numbers...
    next unless looks_like_number( $score );
    # if we don't have a min score defined, or our current 
    # score is less, then store the min and the payload.
    if ( !defined( $min_score ) || $score < $min_score ) { 
        ( $min_score, $min_line ) = ( $score, $_ );
    }
}

say $min_line;
```